# Is there any common CSS styling intended for an img that will behave differently on a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a site that will give users the ability to replace a static image with an Openseadragon tiled image in their webpage.

The user will upload their jpg to our server, our server will create the tiled image, and give the tag the user can place in their web page.

The user can style their page however they want.  If we specify an img tag which the user places in their page, then our javascript copies the classes and style to the created div tag, are there going to be display problems between what the user saw designing the page with the img tag versus the end result with the div tag?  I'm looking for examples of what won't work, perhaps common responsive layout CSS, or what Wordpress might do to their page for styling, etc.

I think it will be better to start with a div with a background image but I need to prove it.

The user will include our img tag on their page so they can apply any css to it.  They include our javascript which searches for the attribute "data-tiledimg" and replaces with the Openseadragon object in a div created with javascript.

Image tag might look like (must have src and data-tiledimg):

```
<img alt="Alternate text" id="img1" class="userClass,userClass2,etc"  style="width:50%;" src="failback.jpg" data-tiledimg="http://tiledimageserver.com/imageID?buttons=pathtobuttons"/>
```

Alternatively the div would be like (our class "resp" to display the background image for failback):

```
<div class="resp,userClass,etc" id="img1" style="width:50%;" data-tiledimg="http://tiledimageserver.com/imageID?buttons=pathtobuttons"/>
```

And the div approach would need css for a background image:

```
.resp{
width:100%;
padding-bottom: 145.27%; /* height/width */
background-image:url(fb2.jpg);
background-size:cover;
//background-position:center; /* IE fix */
```

}

Comment: There could be issues. Consider for example if the user has inline scoped `<style>` tags that reference the `<img>` element. A better approach might be to wrap the image in a `<span>` and make the image itself invisible.

Comment: Is [this](http://openseadragon.github.io/openseadragonizer/) what you are attempting to do? What you trying to describe makes very little sense. The code provided is not enough to understand your objective and/or issue.

Comment: added more details